# How to export the results of an RDS Postgres query into an S3 Parquet file?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-glue, parquet

How do I output the results of an SQL Select query (on an RDS Postgres database) as a Parquet file (into S3)?

Some approaches I'm already considering include AWS Glue (with its JDBC connection), Athena (with its Postgres connector), PostgreSQL itself (with the aws_s3 extension), or a common client like `psql` (perhaps in conjunction with other shell utilities). But I'm not sure what approach would both facilitate parquet-formatted output, and support exporting results of an arbitrary query (say, involving a complicated join) rather than just dumping whole tables? Can I avoid needing to use write access to the database, and constructing an additional view (or table even) to stage the results for each query?

Comment: If you want to stage query results in the database you will need, indeed, to have write access. I don't think you need to do it, though.

The architecture you are looking for will depend on the data lifecycle both in the source database and in the data lake/data warehouse. It would be nice if you could provide a more detailed scenario: how frequently data is updated in the source? How much of this change you want to track on your data lake?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    import psycopg2
    import pandas as pd
    import boto3
    
    # Connect to PostgreSQL
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="your_database", user="your_user", password="your_password", host="your_host", port="your_port")
    query = "SELECT * FROM your_table"
    dataframe = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
    
    # Convert to Parquet format
    dataframe.to_parquet("output.parquet")
    
    # Upload to S3
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    bucket_name = "your-s3-bucket"
    s3.upload_file("output.parquet", bucket_name, "output/output.parquet")
```